# Starting and stopping server script

Tags: python, bash, jmeter

I've been building a performance test suite to exercise a server. Right now I run this by hand but I want to automate it. On the target server I run a python script that logs server metrics and halts when I hit enter. On the tester machine I run a bash script that iterates over JMeter tests, setting timestamps and naming logs and executing the tests.

I want to tie these together so that the bash script drives the whole process, but I am not sure how best to do this. I can start my python script via ssh, but how to halt it when a test is done? If I can do it in ssh then I don't need to mess with existing configuration and that is a big win. The python script is quite simple and I don't mind rewriting it if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to make the Python script respond to signals. Of course, you can just SIGKILL the script if it doesn't require any cleanup, but having the script actually handle a shutdown request seems cleaner. SIGHUP might be a popular choice. Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html).

You can send a signal with the `kill` command so there is no problem sending the signal through ssh, provided you know the pid of the script. The usual solution to this problem is to put the pid in a file in /var/run when you start the script up. (If you've got a Debian/Ubuntu system, you'll probably find that you have the `start-stop-daemon` utility, which will do a lot of the grunt work here.)

Another approach, which is a bit more code-intensive, is to create a fifo (named pipe) in some known location, and use it basically like you are currently using stdin: the server waits for input from the pipe, and when it gets something it recognizes as a command, it executes the command ("quit", for example). That might be overkill for your purpose, but it has the advantage of being a more articulated communications channel than a single hammer-hit.

Comment: Aha!, thanks, rici! Great ideas and I now have new ideas to test. I'll try the first suggestion first as it seems to be the simplest solution. I'd completely overlooked the signal library, this looks exactly like what I imagined I'd need. I'm off to try a solution.

Comment: The answer is good, but after trying a few things I decided to use the OS Process sampler in jmeter. I rewrote my metrics gathering script to allow firing it as a one-shot to gather one data sample and update the log. So, now I can attach it to sampling from client side. This allows me to run a jmeter test stand-alone and get the same output. I still need to play around with it some more, but this looks good so far.